# BigQuery Error loading location is interrupting scheduled queries

Tags: google-bigquery

A few days ago, I started receiving an error in my Scheduled Queries dashboard `Error loading location europe-west8: BigQuery Data Transfer Service does not yet support location: europe-west8`.

I'm in the US, so I have set all 4 of my storage buckets are set to US or REGION, and have confirmed their locations.

[image]

Datasets are all US:
[image]

Scheduled queries are all Region "us"

Since this error started, my BigQuery Scheduled Queries that append data to tables have stopped running.

Where can I change the setting that seems to be calling europe-west8?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the region of the dataset you are using. The destination table for your scheduled query must be in the same region as the data being queried.

You can see the scheduled queries are supported in these locations [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#supported_regions).

You specify a location for storing your BigQuery data when you create a dataset. After you create the dataset, the location cannot be changed, but you can copy the dataset to a different location, or manually move (recreate) the dataset in a different location.

You can see more information about how locations work in BigQuery [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations).

**EDIT**

This is a known issue from BigQuery UI, and the engineering team is aware of and is working towards a solution, although so far there isn't a specific ETA. Feel free to start the [issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to raise further awareness towards it.

There are two possible workarounds you can try to circumvent this.

More specifically,

- **Workaround#1**

  Using the old UI,  you can do it by clicking on "Disable editor
  tabs".

[image]

- **Workaround#2**

  - In Scheduled Query Editor > click the SCHEDULE dropdown > choose "Enable scheduled queries".
  - The overlay shows up with the message box ("Enable scheduled queries").
  - Click anywhere on the screen to close the overlay
  - Click the SCHEDULE dropdown again, and the create/update options are there.

Comment: Thanks!  will look into that solution.

Comment: I checked the location for my datasets, they are all "US".  I used the command line to check each one: bq show --format=prettyjson {PROJECT_ID}:{DATASET_NAME} | grep location
I also checked the Scheduled Queries, they are all Region "us"

Comment: @ljvincent I already update the answer.

Comment: Did Workaround #1 and submitted the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and am trying both workarounds. 

Comment: Update - the workarounds did the trick. Today my scheduled query worked.

Comment: @RaulSaucedo I've tried both workarounds for a couple weeks now, and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running schedule queries check that the processing location is set to the location of your data source and the destination table is also correct.
Checking the docs about setting a query location.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries